# Sharepoint 2013 - Refresh List Item with Data from a Different List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

In Sharepoint 2013 I have 2 (simplified) lists:

### Suppliers

Supplier Number
Buyer Name

### Buyers

Supplier Number
Buyer Name

In the Suppliers list, I need to periodically update the Buyer Name for all rows in the list.  The buyer assignments are periodically changing.

I don't think I can use a lookup field in the Suppliers list because the data is being exported to the list from an Access 2003 database. The Supplier Number is not being manually entered into the list.

What is the best way to create a routine that will get the value in Suppliers.Supplier Number, look it up in the Buyers list, then update Suppliers.Buyer Name with that value, assuming one is found?

I just need to be pointed in the right direction, I think.

Thanks

Mike Thomas

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is feasible with the use of SharePoint Timer Job. Where you can write a logic about reading a one list(Suppliers) and settings its value in the another list(Buyers). You can also set its running time as Daily, Monthly , Yearly or even every minutes

Refrence:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43965/copy-an-item-from-one-list-to-another-list-using-custom-timer-job-creation